# php error array not working

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling, form-submit

I am creating a resume upload portal for applicants and can not get the files to upload. With additional testing, I believe that the issue is my error array. When I intentionally create an error (by not entering the position the applicant is applying for) the error array does not display the error after refreshing the page, post submission. I can not find any mistypes and am not sure where to go from here. I'm thinking fresh eyes and experience will help me resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Form submission page:

```
    ?php require_once("CareerFunctions.inc");
    $Server= "http://localhost/";
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css"></link>
    <title>Career Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Please upload your resume or skip this page and enter it manually.
    <br>
    <br>

    <form action="resumeupload.php" method="post" 

        enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

      <div>
    Select file to upload(Only pdf, Microsoft Office, & Open Office documents are allowed):
    <br>
        <br>
    <div id="ErrorDiv">
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['Error']) && isset($_SESSION['FormAttempt'])){
    unset($_SESSION['FormAttempt']);
    print "Errors Encountered";}
    if (isset ($_SESSION['Error']) && is_array($_SESSION['Error']) && $_SESSION['Error']!==""){
    foreach ($_SESSION['Error'] as $Error) 
    {
    echo "<br>\n" .$Error;
    } //end foreach
    } //end if
    ?>
    </div>
       <br><br>
          <input type="file" id="Upload" name="Upload">
          <br>
          <br>
            Position you are applying for:
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="Position" name="Position">
            <br>
            <br>
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="350000">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
          <br>
        <br>
      </div> 
      <a href="<?php echo $Server?>CareerRegisterManualResume.php">Skip</a>
          <br>
            <div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Form processing page (I have only included the error generating portion):

```
<?php
require_once('CareerFunctions.inc');
if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    die(header("Location:CareerRegisterResume.php"));
$_SESSION['FormAttempt'] = true;
if (isset($_SESSION['Error'])) {
unset($_SESSION['Error']);
}
}
$_SESSION['Error']= array();
if (!preg_match('/\.pdf$/i',$_FILES['Upload']['type']) ||
    !preg_match('/\.doc$/i',$_FILES['Upload']['type']) ||
    !preg_match('/\.docx$/i', $_FILES['Upload']['type'])||
    !preg_match('/\.odt$/i',$_FILES['Upload']['type']))
{$_SESSION['Error'][] = "File type must be a pdf (.pdf), Microsoft Office (.doc or .docx), or Open Office (.odt)";
}
if ($_FILES['Upload']['size'] > '350000')
{$_SESSION['Error'][] = "File is too large for upload!";}
if ($_FILES['Upload']['size'] == '0' || $_FILES['Upload']['size'] = '' || !isset($_FILES['Upload']['size']))
{$_SESSION['Error'][] = "Please select a file for upload";}
if ($_POST['Position']= '' || !isset($_POST['Position']))
{$_SESSION['Error'][]= "Please enter the position you are applying for.";}
if (isset($_FILES['Upload']['error']) && $_FILES['Upload']['error'] > '0' || $_FILES['Upload']['error'] !== '')
{$_SESSION['Error'][]= "There was an issue uploading the file to the server";}

if (count($_SESSION['Error']) > '0')
{die(header("Location: CareerRegisterResume.php"));}

if(UploadResume($_POST)) {
die(header("Location: ApplySuccess.php"));}
else {
error_log("Problem uploading resume: {$_FILES['Upload']['name']}");
$_SESSION['Error'][] = "Problem Uploading Resume";
die(header("Location: CareerRegisterResume.php"));
}
```

Comment: Using proper indentation would be a start. Then, debug your variables and test them with `var_dump` to see what they contain, compare to what you *expect* them to contain. At the moment you're just asking us to debug your code with no clear description; you're in a much better position to do that than we are.

Comment: The `die()` parameter must be a int or string, you cannot execute a function in here. So `die(header());` is invalid.

Comment: Bondye: die(header()); works just fine, I have it throughout my code. It's a more secure method than just using a header() redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
```

to

```
 if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: Thank you for actually listening to what I asked. I asked for another pair of eyes to review the code for mistypes/typos/bad syntax. That fixed the issue. :) Now that the issue has been fixed, I can continue debugging the code as deceze was asking me to do...

Comment: no problem, you should use var_dump and echoing test string in problem places to find error and line in which the script stops